# Django: forms & initial data

Tags: django

In order to display the ticket_reference with `{{ form.initial.ticket_reference }}`, include the field `ticket_reference` in forms.py. While I can hide this field through forms.HiddenInput(), I now wonder if this is 'save'? The user shouldn't be able to change this hidden field, but currently, I think with some knowledgeable people would be able to change this hidden field data, and therefore it's ticket_id. Did you face a similar question before?

.html-file

```
   <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}

        {% for form in formset %}

            <div class="card mt-5">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Ticket ref: {{ form.initial.ticket_reference }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputAddress">{% trans "First name" %}</label>
                            {{ form.first_name }}
                            [...]
```

forms.py

```
class AssignAttendeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Attendee
        fields = (
            'ticket_reference',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'company_name',
            'email',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ticket_reference'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the field's `disabled` attribute to `True`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['ticket_reference'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['ticket_reference'].disabled = True
```

Comment: Ah, and this also makes sure the user can't edit it?

Comment: Just found this here: "The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data."

... perfect! Thank you bdoubleu.

Comment: Yes, here's [`Field.disabled` in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#disabled)